# Prove sequence of random variables is uniformly bounded by constant $c$

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics

Thomas Severini in his "Elements of Distribution Theory" has the following: Assume a sequence of real-valued random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ converges in distribution to $X$. The goal is to show $E(X_n) \rightarrow E(X)$ and so we need an extra condition. Let this condition be:
$$sup_nE[|X_n|\mathbf{1}\{|X_n|\geq c\}]=0$$ for some $c>0$.
Then he concludes that $X_1,X_2,...$ are uniformly bounded since if there exists an $N$ such that $P[|X_N|\geq c]>0$, then
$$E[|X_n|\mathbf{1}\{|X_n|\geq c\}]\geq cP[|X_N|\geq c]>0$$
I think though that the last argument only shows that each $X_1,X_2,...$ is only bounded almost surely by the same $c$.
Uniform boundedness is needed to establish convergence in distribution.

Comment: That condition is quite stringent, it assumes that $|X_n| \leq c$ for all $n$ with probability 1, that is $P(|X_n| \leq c, \forall n) = 1.$ In this sense, the sequence is bounded uniformly by the same constant. Do you have a question?

Comment: In most places bounded uniformly means ||≤ for all . Can this be proven with the conditions listed? Or is the "other sense" of uniformly bounded enough to show convergence in mean?

Comment: You know that $P(|X_n| \leq c) = 1$ for every $n,$ and you also (should) know that $P(\cup E_n) \leq \sum P(E_n)$ for any sequence of events. If the events have probability zero each, then $\cup E_n$ also has probability zero and therefore $\cap E_n^\complement$ has probability one. Let $E_n = \{|X_n| > c\}.$ Then, $P(|X_n| \leq c, \text{ for all }n) = 1.$

Comment: I understand that but that is not equivalent to $|X_n| \leq c$ which is the typical definition for a sequence of RVs to be uniformly bounded. Is your conclusion sufficient to show  $E(X_n) \rightarrow E(X)$ ?

Comment: You are very lost, eh? What you understand as definition and what I wrote are the same, but somehow you can't see that. I don't know very well what conditions guarantee convergence of moments when you only assume convergence in distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have a go at trying to clarify the points you don't appear to be grasping.  I'm not sure I've got them correct, however, so if this doesn't help, please try to explain why in the comments.

As William M. has explained in his comments, the posited condition implies that $\ P\big(|X_n|\le c\ \text{ for all }\ n\big)=$$\,1\ $, and you say you understand this.  It's true that $\ X_n\ $ might not be uniformly bounded on the *whole* of the sample space, $\ \Omega\ $, say, in the sense that $\ \big|\,X_n(\omega)\,\big|<c\ $ might not be true for all $\ n\ $ and *all* $\ \omega\in\Omega\ $. But if we put $\ A=$$\,\big\{\omega\in\Omega\,\big|\, |X_n(\omega)|\le c\ \text{ for all }\ n\big\}\ $ and $\ Y_n=X_n\mathbf{1}_A\ $, then $\ P(A)=1\ $, $\ Y_n\ $ has the same distribution, and hence the same expected value, as $\ X_n\ $, and $\ \big|\,Y_n(\omega)\,\big|<$$\,c\ $ for all $\ n\ $ and all $\ \omega\in\Omega\ $—that is $\ Y_n\ $ *is* uniformly bounded on the *whole* of $\ \Omega\ $. Since $\ Y_n\ $  has the same distribution as $\ X_n\ $ it must also converge in distribution to $\ X\ $. Are you therefore comfortable  with the conclusion that $\ E\big(Y_n\big)\rightarrow E(X)\ $? If so, then you also have $\ E\big(X_n\big)\rightarrow E(X)\ $,  because $\ E\big(X_n\big)= E\big(Y_n\big)\ $.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Severini claimed that the sequence was uniformly bounded and hence convergence in mean followed easily. But I could not see why the sequence was uniformly bounded. Hence, I was suspecting that it was not necessary for $X_n$ to be uniformly bounded on the whole of the sample space for convergence in mean to hold. That was a question in my first comment. Anyway, I understand now.